Airflow ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses
I am running a DAG which invokes an API multiple times and API gets data from a DB. After few invocations, the DAG returns the below error. I am running the DAG in Kubernetes environment.
Could someone redirect me where to check and from where is dag receiving SIGTERM?
Error Logs:

[2024-06-29, 23:46:39 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:115} ERROR -
Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses [2024-06-29, 23:46:39 UTC]
{process_utils.py:131} INFO - Sending 15 to group 28. PIDs of all
processes in the group: [28] [2024-06-29, 23:46:39 UTC]
{process_utils.py:86} INFO - Sending the signal 15 to group 28
[2024-06-29, 23:46:39 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1630} ERROR - Received
SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses. [2024-06-29, 23:46:39 UTC]
{test_driver_airflow.py:648} WARNING - Retrying test [2024-06-29,
23:47:39 UTC] {process_utils.py:149} WARNING - process
psutil.Process(pid=28, name='airflow task runner:test test
manual__2024-06-21T11:04:44+00:00 11476', status='sleeping',
started='18:36:37') did not respond to SIGTERM. Trying SIGKILL
[2024-06-29, 23:47:39 UTC] {process_utils.py:86} INFO - Sending the
signal 9 to group 28 [2024-06-29, 23:47:39 UTC] {process_utils.py:79}
INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=28, name='airflow task runner: test
test manual__2024-06-21T11:04:44+00:00 11476', status='terminated',
exitcode=<Negsignal.SIGKILL: -9>, started='18:36:37') (28) terminated
with exit code -9 [2024-06-29, 23:47:39 UTC]
{standard_task_runner.py:172} ERROR - Job 11476 was killed before it
finished (likely due to running out of memory) [2024-06-29, 23:47:39
UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:228} INFO - Task exited with return
code 143

I checked the logs of API and no errors there. CPU and Memory of pods and nodes are within limits as checked in Grafana.

I believe task status -9 can be any of:

The system killing it due to resource limits.
The system killing it due to timeouts.
An operator (person) explicitly killing it in the GUI.

Since it's in kubernetes, you may find the best way to check is kubectl get events -A and look for Warn events.
Do not rely on Grafana to tell you about OOMs.  A pod can rapidly OOM and crash in < the 30 second scrape interval for promethus; it is super common.  Analyze kubectl for the pod noted in the Airflow GUI and see if it has container restarts, use describe pod to analyze it if you can catch it running.
Also, if this is a Kubernetes Pod Operator task, note that it is very hard to associate the actual pod name to the name in the GUI due to some bugs in recent airflow versions.  So, make sure you are looking at the right task pod ID.
Make sure you carefully read the scheduler log, web server log, and analyze the kubernetes pod states and events.  Usually things are pretty clear for any failure between the 3 if you read carefully.
